# Plugin or method of allowing user to rearrange custom post types with drag and drop?

Tags: custom-post-types, admin

I'm using a custom post type entry to represent each person in an About Us page.  When going to the About Us page, it displays the people in a side menu and if the user clicks on a person's name, it goes to a page about that particular person.

My client wants to be able to order the people in the side menu.  Is there a good way to do this?  I'd prefer to allow the client to drag and drop the posts around to the right order similar to how the [Page Manager](http://plugins.trendwerk.nl/documentation/page-manager/) works, but alas it does not work for custom post types.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [**`Post Types Order`**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-types-order/) plugin which lets you Order Post Types Objects (posts, pages, custom post types) using a Drag and Drop Sortable JavaScript capability

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest [Order Up! Custom Post Order](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/order-up-custom-post-order/) by some guy named me.

It allows you to order posts and custom post types in a drag-n-drop style interface. It also has options which allow automatic sorting of all queries for each post type, which means you don't even have to change your queries in your templates, just check the box and go. You may also manually set `'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC'` if you're writing custom queries on a case by case basis.

There are also two other Order Up! plugins that I've made. [One specifically for pages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/order-up-custom-page-order/) (I separated it from the post order plugin because most users only want to order their pages, and probably wouldn't want all the extra menus for custom post types) and another that can sort [custom taxonomy terms](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/order-up-custom-taxonomy-order/)*.

*The custom taxonomy order plugin still needs work, but the other two are super solid!